# Doing svn export, how to include those haven't yet been checked into repository?

Tags: svn

The reason to do this is that our svn server is down, and I need to export my local copy(which is already latest) ,but how to include those haven't yet been checked into repository?

Answer (score 2):

Create a copy of your working copy, and remove the hidden `.svn` folders and their contents from that copy.